# kernel driver to repond specific packate over ethernet

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In my application client is going to send one command in UDP packet.
I want to receive this packet in kernel and send its responce as soon as possible.
I know i can achieve this by creating application in linux userspace but there is delay when i receive package in user space.
To avoid this delay i want to send response from kernel space.
my question is how can i write specific code to run in kernel space? 
Does it is similar to writing drivers? or Any other method is there to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it is similar to writing drivers?

Not exactly. Network drivers are designed to serve a well-defined network stack API to forward packets back and forth between the kernel and the hardware. And, although your task *may* be solved by writing a custom network driver or furnishing an existing one with some extensions, this might be a dubious choice.

In fact, apart from modifying the kernel code, there is a handful of solutions commonly known as **kernel bypass** and/or **zero-copy** techniques.
For instance, you still can write a user-space application to serve the commands with lower latency, provided that you use a [PACKET_MMAP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt) mechanism which strictly speaking is not a kernel bypass but a facility within Linux kernel. It allows one to make a *direct memory mapping* for software Rx and Tx rings from the userland to kernel side. Thus it could reduce latency significantly. However, the feature assumes a *packet* socket, so a typical application has to parse the packet headers on Rx and prepare them on Tx itself. Hopefully, it's not a tough task to perform.

Also, multiple bona fide kernel bypass techniques exist which commonly base on the concept of [user-space drivers](https://lwn.net/Articles/232575/). Basically, a special in-kernel helper driver is used to make some of device's resources available in the userland. Then a user-space driver may pick those resources and manage the NIC directly without any kernel involvement. Typically, such user-space drivers are combined with helper libraries and distributed as *frameworks*, in example, like the [dataplane kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Plane_Development_Kit) (please find there a link to the actual website).

To put it together, most likely you may avoid any kernel modifications to solve your problem since more flexible techniques exist.